# NodeJs - How to redirect to a specific page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently using a NodeJS server. I verify a condition with a `if` statement. If the `credential`s are not valid, for example, how to send the user to a specific page?

```
if (credentials) {
   // go to the main page
}
else {
   // go the login page
}
```

Comment: Are you using just Node.js's built-in HTTP APIs, or a framework like Express or Koa? What has your research turned up?

Comment: `NodeJs server` What's that?.

Comment: Currently I'm using Express and the build-in HTTP API

Comment: app.get('/informations.html', function(req, res)
{
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/informations.html');
});

Comment: @ Keith hosting a website with Nodejs, the back-end is a javascript program

Comment: Kinda answering your own question no? if credentials return main.html else return login.html ? You know the code to send a page since you show it here.

Answer (score 1):

You've said you're using ExpressJS. In ExpressJS, you do a redirect via [`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect):

> **`res.redirect([status,] path)`**
>
> Redirects to the URL derived from the specified `path`, with specified `status`, a positive integer that corresponds to an HTTP status code . If not specified, `status` defaults to “302 “Found”.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to establish what kind of authentication you are using. There are a million ways to do this, but if you are less familiar with auth systems, I would recommend using a third-party auth system like [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/) or [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) login. Those would generally give you some kind of auth token on login, and essentially you could just check to see if the stored token is there, whether that be in cache, cookies, local storage, etc., and if it has not expired. If all is good, keep going, if not, then redirect to the login page.

If you want to make this more secure, don't write any of credential validation on the client side. Have the client's browser check for the auth token and its recency, then send it to the server. The server would then respond by routing you to the proper page.

Another method that should probably be used in tandem with this would be to check for a valid login on every single page where the user would need to be logged in, as opposed to only having the one page that redirects to either a login screen or where you want to go.

Comment: *"First, you need to establish what kind of authentication you are using..."* Um...why?

Comment: Your answer is good but I'm having technical difficulties not a architecture one